# How to slice a list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, slice

Alright, I am pretty new to programming but I do know that 0-0 == 0. Can anyone explain Why I get this error?

[image: error]

I have searched high and low and cannot explain this. Every implementation of slicing that I've seen is done like this (except for using built in function, which is not allowed for what I'm doing).

Comment: Please next time include your code as *text*, not an image.

Comment: Please exclude your image and show your exception here

Comment: Do not post your code as a picture

Comment: What is the value of "i" when you encounter this error. Also what is the length of list when it hits it?

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple way for you to do this slicing operation using extension methods, see the code below:

```
public static List<int> Slice(List<int> inputList, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{ 
    int elementCount = endIndex-startIndex + 1;
    return inputList.Skip(startIndex).Take(elementCount).ToList();
}
```

Here is a [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IbHwhn) for you.

Answer (score 2):

This one

```
new List<int>(...)
```

creates **empty** list, so there's no element with index 0 there.

Comment: This one `new List<T>(int)` creates a list with a certain starting capacity.

Comment: @lanH not exactly. That's just a size of internal array so list won't resize until this amount of elements are added. Referencing elements still not allowed until they are `Add`-ed

Comment: @IanH. With a starting capacity, yes. Capacity doesn't determine whether or not it contains elements. A big empty cup doesn't have any more water than a small empty cup.

Answer (score 1):

When implementing *public* methods, add *validation* and *generalize* the method:

```
//DONE: <T> - generalize - what if you want to slice, say, List<long> or List<string>?
//DONE: IEnumerable<T> - generalize: waht if you want to slice, an array, int[]? 
//DONE: we usually put public methods in Pascal case: Slice, not slice
public static List<T> Slice<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
  //DONE: validation
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  else if (startIndex < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", 
      $"startIndex ({startIndex}) must be non-negative.");
  else if (startIndex > endIndex)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", 
      $"startIndex ({startIndex}) must not exceed endIndex ({endIndex}).");

  // Instead of pure Linq 
  // return source.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex).ToList();
  // let's use a loop

  // it doesn't create endIndex - startIndex items but reserve space for them
  List<T> result = new List<T>(endIndex - startIndex);

  foreach (var item in source.Skip(startIndex))
    if (result.Count >= endIndex - startIndex)
      return result;
    else
      result.Add(item); // we add items, not put them with result[i] = ...

  // source exhausted, but we don't reach endIndex. 
  //TODO: Shall we return as is or throw an exception?
  return result;
}
```

So you can do

```
// please, notice: not necessary List, not necessary of int
string[] test = new string[] {"A", "B", "C"};

List<string> slice = test.Slice(0, 1);
```